# Sum Pyramid with backtracking

Tags: algorithm, sum, backtracking

I'm trying to solve this problem and I'm new to backtracking algorithms,
The problem is about making a pyramid like this so that a number sitting on two numbers is the sum of them. Every number in the pyramid has to be different and less than 100. Like this:

```
     88
   39  49
  15  24  25
 4  11  13  12
1  3   8   5   7
```

Any pointers on how to do this using backtracking?

Comment: I think it would help if you provided more instructions, such as how many total numbers there should be in the pyramid, or any other requirement.

Comment: I assume the whole thing is about: given a number N (N<100) creates the tallest pyramid possible such as a number sitting on two numbers is the sum of them.

Comment: ... and the resulting pyramid has N as its top...

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily backtracking but the property you are asking for is interestingly very similar to the Pascal Triangle property.

The Pascal Triangle (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal's_triangle), which is used for efficient computation of binomial coefficient among other things, is a pyramid where a number is equal to the sum of the two numbers above it with the top being 1.

As you can see you are asking the opposite property where a number is the sum of the numbers below it.

```
                1
              1   1
            1   2   1
          1   3   3   1
        1   4   6   4   1
      1   5  10  10   5   1
    1   6  15  20  15   6   1
  1   7  21  35  35  21   7   1
1   8  28  56  70  56  28   8   1
```

For instance in the Pascal Triangle above, if you wanted the top of your pyramid to be 56, your pyramid will be a reconstruction bottom up of the Pascal Triangle starting from 56 and that will give something like:

```
                 56
              21    35
            6    15    20
         1     5    10    10
```

Again that's not a backtracking solution and this might not give you a good enough solution for every single N though I thought this was an interesting approximation that was worth noting.